# Migation of vTiger to new server

Tags: database-migration, vtiger

I am trying to move our vtiger to a new server. I followed these steps

1. zipped all files and folders for vtiger.
2. dumped the sql
3. unzipped the files on the new server.
4. restored the database with new username and password. Then updated the file

config.db.php

After this I try to load and get the following errors.

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of dbTable::create() should be compatible with dbObject::create() in /home/teldio/public_html/crm/adodb/adodb-xmlschema.inc.php on line 605

Strict Standards: Declaration of dbIndex::create() should be compatible with dbObject::create() in /home/teldio/public_html/crm/adodb/adodb-xmlschema.inc.php on line 769

Strict Standards: Declaration of dbData::create() should be compatible with dbObject::create() in /home/teldio/public_html/crm/adodb/adodb-xmlschema.inc.php on line 956

Strict Standards: Declaration of dbQuerySet::create() should be compatible with dbObject::create() in /home/teldio/public_html/crm/adodb/adodb-xmlschema.inc.php on line 1207

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/teldio/public_html/crm/include/database/PearDatabase.php on line 20

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/teldio/public_html/crm/include/database/PearDatabase.php on line 21

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/teldio/public_html/crm/include/database/PearDatabase.php on line 936

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/teldio/public_html/crm/include/database/PearDatabase.php on line 232

Warning: mysql_pconnect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/teldio/public_html/crm/adodb/drivers/adodb-mysql.inc.php on line 373

Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _FILES in /home/teldio/public_html/crm/include/utils/CommonUtils.php on line 1577
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to eliminate php5 Strict standards errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229113/how-to-eliminate-php5-strict-standards-errors)

Comment: I do not want to hide errors I want to fix them....

Comment: Your messages are appearing because of a change made in the way error reporting is done in PHP 5.4. The same 'errors' occurred in PHP 5.3 but weren't reported by default. If you want to fix these 'errors' you'll need to modify some of the code in deeper parts of vTiger. Alternatively, you can simply set error reporting to the 5.3 standard, or configure your hosting system to use PHP 5.3 (but this isn't always possible.

Comment: I've found vTiger 5.4 to be practically unusable on PHP 5.4, so sticking to 5.3 may be a good idea. Also some are not errors like "Strict Standards" and "Warning". Only "Fatal error" is a real error the will halt the execution.

Comment: This looks like an authentication error on the MySQL server too. Maybe that causes the next line?