# Strict standards non static method

Tags: php, standards, anonymous-function, strict

I want to fix this error:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method
>   Gpf_Settings_Regional::getInstance() should not be called statically,
>   assuming $this from incompatible context on line 39

The code producing it:

```
$this->addValue(Gpf_Settings_Gpf::REGIONAL_SETTINGS_DECIMAL_SEPARATOR, 
Gpf_Settings_Regional::getInstance()->getDecimalSeparator());
```

I know this is method for PHP 5.3, but I have 5.4 on shared hosting and need to call static on PHP 5.4

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

You are accessing a non-static method statically with strict standards error reporting switched on.

**Solutions:**

You can update Gpf_Settings_Regional class

change

```
public function getInstance()
```

to

```
public static function getInstance()
```

If you are unable to change that class you can change error reporting and switch of reporting of strict standards errors, but it would be better to improve the code.

[How to eliminate php5 Strict standards errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229113/how-to-eliminate-php5-strict-standards-errors)

Answer (score 0):

if i see good it's already made it by script

*/
    private static $instance;

```
public static function create(Gpf_Application $application) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en.UTF-8');
    self::$instance = $application;
    self::$instance->registerRolePrivileges();
    self::$instance->initLogger();
    self::$instance->addSmartyPluginsDir();
    $timezone = Gpf_Settings_Gpf::DEFAULT_TIMEZONE;
    try {
        $timezone = Gpf_Settings::get(Gpf_Settings_Gpf::TIMEZONE_NAME);
    } catch (Gpf_Exception $e) {
        Gpf_Log::error('Unable to load timezone: %s - using default one.', $e->getMessage());
    }
    if(false === @date_default_timezone_set($timezone)) {
        Gpf_Log::error('Unable to set timezone %s:', $timezone);
    }
}

public function getDefaultLanguage() {
    return 'en-US';
}

/**
 * @return Gpf_Application
 */
public static function getInstance() {
    if(self::$instance === null) {
        throw new Gpf_Exception('Application not initialize');
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

and this is part where problem is

abstract class Gpf_ApplicationSettings extends Gpf_Object {

```
/**
 * @var Gpf_Data_RecordSet
 */
private $recordSet;

const CODE = "code";
const VALUE = "value";

protected function loadSetting() {
    $this->addValue("theme", Gpf_Session::getAuthUser()->getTheme());
    $this->addValue("date_time_format", 'MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    $this->addValue("programVersion", Gpf_Application::getInstance()->getVersion());
    $this->addValue(Gpf_Settings_Gpf::NOT_FORCE_EMAIL_USERNAMES, Gpf_Settings::get(Gpf_Settings_Gpf::NOT_FORCE_EMAIL_USERNAMES));

    $quickLaunchSettings = new Gpf_Desktop_QuickLaunch();
    $this->addValue(Gpf_Desktop_QuickLaunch::SHOW_QUICK_LAUNCH, $quickLaunchSettings->getShowQuickLaunch());

    $this->addValue(Gpf_Settings_Gpf::REGIONAL_SETTINGS_THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR,
```

Gpf_Settings_Regional::getinstance()->getThousandsSeparator());
        $this->addValue(Gpf_Settings_Gpf::REGIONAL_SETTINGS_DECIMAL_SEPARATOR, Gpf_Settings_Regional::getInstance()->getDecimalSeparator());
        $this->addValue(Gpf_Settings_Gpf::REGIONAL_SETTINGS_DATE_FORMAT, Gpf_Settings_Regional::getInstance()->getDateFormat());
        $this->addValue(Gpf_Settings_Gpf::REGIONAL_SETTINGS_TIME_FORMAT, Gpf_Settings_Regional::getInstance()->getTimeFormat());

```
    Gpf_Plugins_Engine::extensionPoint('Core.loadSetting', $this);
}
```